# How to write a web server to handle post (content-type is application/json) in python?

Tags: python, webserver

Here comes the detail:

We want to write a web server in Python v2.6.5, and have finished the `do_GET` method.

But I don't know how to write the `do_POST()` method.

If the post request goes like the following:

```
POST /employee/111 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: XX

{"name": "John"}
```

How to get the JSON data `{"name": "John"}` in `do_POST()` method?
(prefer standard library)

It'd be greatly appreciated if you can eloborate why and give a sample.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `cgi.FieldStorage` class to to handle the data as a form-data avaiable from the POST..
And when you go the portion which is the body of the POST and which in your case is in `json` format.

```
def do_POST(self):
    # Parse the form data posted
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile, 
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })
```

Here is [an example](http://web.archive.org/web/20130822231715/http://doughellmann.com/2007/12/pymotw-basehttpserver.html) illustrating how to do that

And if the content is a proper json, use the json module from the standard library to load to json format and you can deal with it further.

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '{"name": "john"}'
>>> d = json.loads(s)
```

Comment: Link is broken, would like to see the portion about handling the body of the post

Answer (score 0):

In your post, the element `{"name": "John"}` is just a string that needs to be json parsed. So first import the `json` module and then do `json.load`.

```
import json
post_json_data = json.loads('{"name": "John"}')
```

To detect where the json data starts you just need to read up to the first `{`, everything from there should be part of the json data.